# Could someone clarify this block for me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I was dealing with a problem in which an object used inside a block wouldn't release.

First I had this code:

```
__block SOMABannerView* bannerView=_bannerView;
self.viewWillDissappearObserver = [center addObserverForName:UIViewWillDissappearNotification object:self.delegate.viewControllerForPresentingModalView queue:mainQueue usingBlock:
    ^(NSNotification *note) {
        [bannerView setAutoReloadEnabled:NO];
     }];
```

I used __block because it supposedly wouldn't copy and retain the object , but when I was analyzing this code with Instruments I noticed the objects from class SOMABannerView weren't being deallocated, so I changed it to:

```
self.viewWillDissappearObserver = [center addObserverForName:UIViewWillDissappearNotification object:self.delegate.viewControllerForPresentingModalView queue:mainQueue usingBlock:
    ^(NSNotification *note) {
        [_bannerView setAutoReloadEnabled:NO];
     }];
```

Which didn't work either, so I ended up using another method from NSNotificationCenter to avoid the block, but still I don't get why the __block was retaining the object, Could somebody clarify this for me? Do i have a wrong concept of __block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't retain the object in a non-ARC environment, but it *will* in an ARC environment.  For ARC, use `__weak` instead of `__block`.

Source: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks

Comment: "For ARC, use __weak" or `__unsafe_unretained`, if `__weak` is not available

Comment: @newacct Good point.  I haven't developed for iOS 4 in a couple years now ^^;